# Am I going insane or is jsFiddle buggy?

Tags: javascript, jsfiddle

Here is my little debugging alert. Almost threw my monitor out of the window.
Look only on the highlighted code. On what conditions on earth could this alert be triggered like that? - https://i.stack.imgur.com/nrf1x.png

Here is full fiddle, but I don't think it's important: http://jsfiddle.net/Timson/QqVrF/8/

```
if (currLoad > maxload){
    alert("I am dumbass, I think that "+currLoad+' is more than '+maxload);
}
```

Comment: When I press the button on the fiddle I don't get that error? Should I? Can you reduce your code until you stop it happening, then build it back up again till it does?

Comment: i can't read whatever language that is, can you provide steps to recreate and/or reduce the problem to its simplest form?

Answer (score 4):

Is it possible that the variables are both strings? In a javascript console:

```
6 > 1000
  false

"6" > "1000"
  true
```

Answer (score 0):

try :

```
if (parseInt(currLoad) > parseInt(maxload)){
            alert("I am dumbass, I think that "+currLoad+' is more than '+maxload);
        }
```

As the earlier answer said you're probably comparing strings..

Answer (score 0):

You get these values from form inputs so they are strings. Comparing strings is different than numbers so `"6" > "1000"` is true while `6 > 1000` is false.

Each number you obtain from form inputs should be parsed to number if it's supposed to be a number. Use for example `parseInt` or `Number` function. For instance: `parseInt(currLoad, 10)` etc.

Comment: It is correct.But I was so confused because other operators work just fine without converting data type manually. Adding, dividing and multiplying. I guess JS automatic data type conversion spoiled me.

Comment: That's right. You need to be really careful. E.g. multiplication operator only works with numbers in JS so it converts strings to numbers. But other operators like `<, >, +` works with strings too. So for instance, if you use `+` operator with number and string, it converts number to string and concatenates them. But `<` and `>` work contrary.